# Removing elements with the same priority from a PriorityQueue

Tags: java

While executing this code:

```
Queue q=new PriorityQueue();
q.add(1);
q.add(1);
q.add(1);
q.add(2);
System.out.println(q);
System.out.println(q.remove(1));
System.out.println(q);
```

The output is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2]
true
[1, 2, 1]
```

Could someone please explain the reason for this shifting in the value of 1 in the output?

Comment: It's a _priority queue_ items are probably arranged by a min/max heap, what did you expect?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `System.out.println(q`);  prints the elements returned by PriorityQueue.iterator and PriorityQueue API says

```
The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).
```